# Is there a template or something for generating a switch statement for Java enum in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, code-generation, switch-statement

Is there a template or something for generating a switch statement for Java enum in Eclipse?

So that when I got an enum and I want to have a switch with all the values, I didn't have to write all it myself?

Comment: Not answering your question but you may want to consider the “replace switch with polymorphism” refactoring.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859563/java-enums-and-switch-statements-the-default-case for a better way than using switch. In short visitor pattern.

Comment: As a note to the above two comments, there are plenty of situations where switch on an enum is valid. If the enum is being used as a "type code", polymorphism is likely a better option. If the enum represents states, then the link kts points out is useful (the answer in there is basically the GoF state pattern implemented in an enum)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There certainly is, at least in 3.5.

Starting with something like this:

```
switch(a.getType()){

}
```

All you need to do is click on the switch keyword and hit CTRL+1.  You should get a drop down which includes the option "Add missing case statements"

Comment: Nice, thanks. And in addition to this, using Ctrl-1 suggestions also with other cases than plain problems is a good thing to know.

Comment: +1. Note that if "Enum type constant not covered on 'switch'" is set to generate a warning/error, CTRL+1 on that line does not work. You have to select the `switch` keyword and then press CTRL+1.

Answer (score 1):

The content assists in Eclipse 3.4 will help you write the code. Just type `case` and press Ctrl+Space and you'll get a list of unused enums.

Comment: Yes, but then I still got to write each one separately even though the completion speeds the process up.

Comment: you may try out http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#createswitchcaseenum..with this one can generate switch-case/if-else-if structure of specific enum. This plugin has many other useful features, you may have a look at  http://3pintech.com/products.htm.