# Java Enums - Switch statements vs Visitor Pattern on Enums - Performance benefits?

Tags: java, enums, performance, switch-statement, visitor-pattern

I have been searching around for days to find an answer to this performance based issue.
After digging  the Internet so far I have learned that there are couple of ways to use the Enums in java, well documented in [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).
Well, definitely as a starter one would like use Enums in a *switch-case* statement, which provides clarity and better understanding of the code. But on the other hand we have a *Visitor pattern* style implementation of the Enums as well, which ensures type safety and extensibility, Discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859563/java-enums-and-switch-statements-the-default-case).

Having said that, and coming back to original idea behind this question, so far I have learned that if a switch-case construct is properly designed using Enums, which ensures that case values are not sparse, and that the Enum declaration is in the same compilation unit as the switch-case statement, the java compiler performs some optimisation on the produced byte-code by implementing such construct as a **Jump Table** (discussed in [here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=504) and elsewhere as well on Sun's website, to which I lost the link). Now, this definitely gives a boost to the performance compared to multiple/nested if-else construct.

My question is, how does java implement the visitor pattern based implementation of Enums in the resulting byte-code and what is the performance boost while compared to *switch-case* based implementation, if any?

And which type of implementation should I prefer, considering my Enums may grow in future and I am keen on performance as well. Currently, I have some 19 and odd constants in my Enum.

---

**EDIT**
I have a class that stores some information about variables of a game. One of the variables being an *Enum* type.

```
public class GameObject {
    private Shape mShape;

    public Shape getShape() {
        return mShape;
    }
    .
    .
    .

    public static enum Shape {
        SHAPE1, SHAPE2, SHAPE3, SHAPE4, ..., SHAPE20
    };

    public void drawShape() {
        switch (this.mShape) {
        case SHAPE1:
            drawShape1();
            break;
        case SHAPE2:
            drawShape2();
            break;
        case SHAPE3:
            drawShape3();
            break;
        case SHAPE4:
            drawShape4();
            break;
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        case SHAPE20:
            drawShape20();
            break;
        default:
            drawUnknown();
            break;
        }
    }
```

}

Later I realised of separating the information from logic, and hence created another class and moved the ***Enum Shape*** from ***GameObject*** to this new class ***GraphicModel***, and instead of having *switch-case* there, I implemented *constant-specific methods*. And yes I did put proper import statements in either class after this modification.

```
public class GraphicModel {
    public void drawGraphicFromObject(GameObject gameObject) {
        gameObject.getShape().draw();
    }

    public static enum Shape {
        // This method is not public, instead is only called by GraphicModel
        abstract void draw();

        SHAPE1 {
            @Override
            void draw() {
                // some transformations
            }
        },
        SHAPE2 {
            @Override
            void draw() {
                // Some different transformation
            }
        },
        SHAPE3 {
            @Override
            void draw() {
                // Yet another transform
            }
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        UNKNOWN {
            @Override
            void draw() {
                // 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Later on I even implemented this based on *visitor pattern* as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859563/java-enums-and-switch-statements-the-default-case)

So, what I need to know is that which way of implementation is more efficient? Definitely, for *switch-case* to be converted to **jump tables** on compilation, java requires both *enum* declaration and *switch* statements in the same *compilation unit*.
Should I use *switch* based implementation or *constant-specific method* implementation in my **GraphicModel** class?
Rather, to be clear, what's the difference in performance?

Comment: Do you have an example of the most clearly written code and a spec and test results showing how it doesn't meat the spec?  If not, you shouldn't be thinking along these lines yet.  If so, post the clearly written code and I bet we could find some much more significant optimizations.

Comment: The linked SO question tells how Enums can be used with Visitor pattern and not "visitor pattern implementation of Enums'. I think it would better if you tell what is the problem you are trying to solve. Once if you see the enums can be used as a solution to your problem then you can see if it needs to be optimized.

Comment: This sounds like the type of micro-micro-micro-optimization which has no discernible effect in 99.99% of cases

Comment: I apologise if I was not able put forth my understanding properly in formal terms, to be honest I never got hang of such terms, although I have been using such methodologies. And I believe, yes I did use the wrong term here, like mentioned in the post by Dieter, it's called constant-specific method implementation. And I will post a sample code of what I meant by today. It was 5 in the morning here when I posted. 
Thanks everyone for the pointers. I agree with Matt, yet my question remains, which is more efficient even if it brings just a micro-minimal boost?

Comment: The second is more of a Strategy than a Visitor pattern.

Comment: In Effective Jave, 2nd Ed., J. Bloch makes a compelling argument that switch-case blocks should not routinely be used to iterate over enum constants.  He goes on to develop the idea that using constant-specific methods in place of switch-case can often lead to less fragile, more easily maintainable code.  Applying this reasoning to your question, I would say that the performance issues are not likely to be important (you'd have to profile to see), but the software engineering benefits of the constant-specific methods pattern favor their use over switch-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums are, generally speaking, comparable in performance to *int* constants, if used in a *switch* statement ([1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)).

Maybe you should rather consider something along the lines of *constant specific method implementations*? e.g.

```
public enum Mode {

  ON { Color color() {return Color.GREEN;}},
  OFF { Color color() {return Color.RED;}},
  STANDBY { Color color() {return Color.YELLOW;}},
  DEFAULT { Color color() {return Color.BLACK;}};

  abstract Color color();

}//enum Mode
```

And then use

```
getMode().color();
```

instead of a *switch* statement?!

However, I think that for a "get a color only case", there is maybe no need for methods at all.

In general, I highly recommend you [*Effective Java*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) for your bookshelf. Chapter 6 would be the one that discusses *Enums and Annotations*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, nevertheless that was exactly what I did the second time. I'll have a look at the book as well.